# use R: fit a set of data with an horizontal line

Tags: r, data-fitting, horizontal-line

I have a question about fitting data set.

I have a set of data, I want to plot it and add a horizontal line which should be the best fit of it.(let's say it is Y=a and ignore the shape of data)

How can I find a? which method i need to use.

I prefer to use R, but also ok for MATLAB

Comment: The answers below are very sensible and standard.  Under other circumstances you might choose the median of the data rather than the mean (i.e., minimize the sum of absolute deviations rather than the sum of squared deviations).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mean of `Y` would be the best fit in this case.

```
Y=rnorm(100)
plot(Y)
abline(h=mean(Y))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> I have a set of data, I want to plot it

You can use the plot() function for this

```
x <- runif(100)
y <- 5 + 5*x + rnorm(100)

df <- data.frame(x, y)
plot(y ~ x, data = df)
```

> add a horizontal line which should be the best fit of it.

The best horizontal line would be the mean of your y-values:

```
abline(h = my, mean(df$y))
```

Comment: Thank you for you help! but in my case x is the a fixed number.